# Wine hide/corrupt my files from Ubuntu on external drive

Tags: 22.04, wine

I'm using AIMP (wine) to open music from my external SSD. For some time everything was good until recently, when I have got disappeared all my music from the directory on the external drive. The interesting thing is that I am still able to play music via AIMP (on the screenshot you can see the full Wine path to the files, despite it being a little bit strange with the main directory and file name stuck together)

[image: screenshot]

But when I open the directory via Ubuntu Files via Wine path `~/.wine/dosdevices/d:/Music/main` or directly on the external drive, I don't see any files there.

How can I find my files?